# Get parameter value using 'Reflect'

Tags: java, abstract, reflect

I'm still playing with Java and I've not experience....
Ok, my question is:
is it possible to get, dynamically, the value of fields of a class ?
Here with an example: The 'My_Zoo' is my class, which can have different fields 'animal', ie. dog1, dog2, chitchen1,...

But I want to get their value (i.e. common field 'Number_of_arms') dynamically.

So, for the class My_Zoo I have only one Field variable and from It I want to get the value 'Number_of_arms'.

The reason why I'm using abstract class is that I home to say to the system: 
'*the Field field is an 'animal' type then give me the value of parameter 'Number_of_arms'*'

Is it possible ?

```
    public class My_Zoo{

        public abstract class Animal{
            String name;
            String color;
            int Number_of_arms;
            public String getName(){
                return name;
            }
            public int getNumber_of_arms(){
                return Number_of_arms;
            }            
        }

        public class Dog extends Animal{
            public Dog(String name, String color){
                this.name = name;
                this.color = color;
                this.Number_of_arms = 4;
            }
        }

        public class Chicken extends Animal{
            public Chicken(String name, String color){
                this.name = name;
                this.color = color;
                this.Number_of_arms = 2;
            }        
        }

        Dog dog_Charlie = new Dog("Charlie", "black");
        Dog dog_Bobo = new Dog("Bobo", "brawn");
        Chicken chicken_Princess = new Chicken("Princess", "brawn"); 

        public My_Zoo(){
            Field[] fields = this.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
            int Number_of_arms;

            for (Field field: fields){
                ??? Number_of_arms = field...Number_of_arms ???
            }
        }
    }
```

In the code, the row `??? Number_of_arms = field...Number_of_arms ???` is missing. What I have to use?

Thank you

Comment: So fetch the value of the field using `field.get()`, then cast that to `Animal`, and call `getNumber_of_arms` on that `Animal` reference.

Comment: Yes, ok, but even if `Animal` is an abstract class ? Is it possible ?

Comment: I wouldn't have suggested it if it wouldn't work... when someone suggests something, it's always worth *trying* it before questioning whether or not it'll work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope it will help you:

```
for (Field field : fields) {
    Animal temp = (Animal) field.get(this);
        System.out.println(temp.getName() + ": " + temp.getNumber_of_arms());
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it's possible.

Example:

Your object is: Animal animal;

and you want to get value of fields in animal object.

```
Field[] fields = Animal.class.getDeclaredFields();
for(Field field:fields){
    if(field.getName().contains("Number_of_arms")){
        int Number_of_arms = field.getInt(animal);
    }
}
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html

Comment: No, the class with this code in doesn't contain `Number_of_arms` - it contains fields with animal references in. The OP needs to call `field.get()` to retrieve the animal reference, cast to `Animal`, then they can access the field/method for the number of arms.

Comment: don't notice about parent class, i just want to focus the possibility of using reflex. By the way, i edited it.

Comment: But your edit misses the point of what the OP is trying to do. They're trying to find all the `Animal` fields in their class. They don't need to (and shouldn't) use reflection to get the `Number_of_arms` field. They only need reflection to get the animal fields.